# Load a fake map on osmdroid map in android

Tags: android, osmdroid

I need overlay an map image on a MapView, which will hide the the real map from the user
when user offline   i want  to show fake map instead of
[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Besides photoshop, you can put a basic image view on top of the map, but it wouldn't react the same way the map does to touch inputs. Not sure what goal is. If you want offline maps, there's always this
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles

Comment: the thing is i don't know where user will use app, i can't donload  all world map into app
i want  show  user fake map, for exemple simple green tiles